# Eclipse for OSX creating desktop shortcuts on every startup

Tags: eclipse, osx-elcapitan

As in the title, ever since the update to Mars.2 (4.5.2) the IDE automatically creates a broken shortcut on the desktop. The shortcut comes with a missing icon and doesn't actually work. How do I disable it?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean an alias...What does the alias point to? Can you show us what you see when you do *Get Info...* on it?

Comment: Sure, it looks like this: [link](http://i66.tinypic.com/2duz8t4.png)

Comment: Eclipse doesn't generally create aliases/shortcuts of any kind; I've used versions of Eclipse on OS X for 6+ years and never seen it happen. Is there any chance you have some third-party plugin installed that might be doing it? Or some OS X extension? Can you capture a video of this happening?